# setting nginx proxy_pass on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to set proxy_pass for some specific location.
Locally in react I'm using proxy-middleware and my config looks like this

```
app.use(
    "/firebase",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/poplco.appspot.com/o/",
      pathRewrite: { "^/firebase": "/" },
      headers: { "X-Forwarded-Prefix": "/" },
      changeOrigin: true,
    }),
  );
```

and when I'm calling this

```
fetch(`/firebase/logos%2F${profile.generalSettingsData[3]}?alt=media`)
```

it works perfectly.
But for production I'm using ubuntu server with nginx and trying to set location rules. for this
I've tried

```
location /firebase {
       proxy_pass         https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/poplco.appspot.com/o/;
    }
```

of course it isn't work. As I see I should set rewrite rules to handle dynamically path params from my request, cause file name is dynamically changing path parameter.
Somebody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed. the final code
front

```
axios({
          baseURL: "/v0",
          url: `/b/poplco.appspot.com/o/logos%2F${profile.generalSettingsData[3]}`,
          method: "GET",
          responseType: "blob",
        })
          .then((res) => {
            convertBlobToBase64(res.data)
              .then((base64) => setImage(base64))
              .catch((error) => console.log(error));
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log("error", { ...err }));
      }
```

and nginx

```
 location /v0/ {
       resolver 8.8.8.8;
       proxy_pass         https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com$request_uri?alt=media;
    }
```

the main problem with nginx was in resolver 8.8.8.8. Even when I'm see in nginx logs absolutely correctly rewritten, I'm getting error 502. after detailed researching logs I've found next error[image]
In addition to it I've got lot of troubles with %2F that nginx encoding/decoding just in / or %252F, but it's another story and I found lot of issues here on this point